# Unable to install/activate .NET Framework

Tags: windows-8, installation, .net-framework

On one of my Windows 8 computers (running Windows 8.1 RT), .NET Framework seems to be not on my Programs and Features list.
[image: .NET Framework - Not there.]

On my other Windows 8 computer (running Windows 8.1), .NET Framework is shown.
[image: .NET Framework - At the very top]

Is there any way to install it (.NET Framework 2.0/3.5/4.5) on my Windows 8 RT computer?
I've tried the installers from the Microsoft download center and nothing works. I always get:
*Installer links are placed as notes and are not shown. (Please see question's source; click the "Edited by [someone] at [sometime]" link)*

[image: "This app can't run on your PC"]

Comment: Both identical versions of Windows 8? RT? 8? 8.1? I say RT because a computer is quite a general term!  ;)

Comment: Why do you want to remove the .NET Framework exactly?  You can't run desktop installers for obvious reasons on a Windows RT device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the arm version you can't run any desktop applications, so .Net 3.5 is not available to install. All store app depend on .Net 4.5.x.